# C++ Access Violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working on an existing data parsing program that overlays a struct onto a buffer in order to extract values.  Recently a new data format has been added to the buffer and requires a new struct.  I abstracted functions into a common base class and defined a new struct like this:

```
struct Header
{
    Header () { }

public:
    virtual unsigned __int8 getCommonField1() const = 0;
}

struct HeaderTypeA : public Header
{
    unsigned __int8 Field1;

public:
    unsigned __int8 getCommonField1() const { return Field1; }
}

struct HeaderTypeB : public Header
{
    unsigned __int8 Field0;
    unsigned __int8 Field1;

public:
    unsigned __int8 getCommonField1() const { return Field1; }
}
```

The existing code which does the processing evaluates the data (this is working) and returns a pointer to the calling function... something like this:

```
Header* parse()
{    
    Header* parsedHeader = 0;

    if (typeADetected)
    {
        parsedHeader = (HeaderTypeA *) &buffer[offset];
        // Other logic here...
    }
    else if (typeBDetected)
    {
        parsedHeader = (HeaderTypeB *) &buffer[offset];
        // Other logic here...
    }

    return (parsedHeader);
}
```

The problem arises in the caller of the parsing logic.  When the header is returned as a pointer the calls to the member functions result in an access violation error:

```
Header * hdr;
hdr = m_parser->parse();
unsigned __int8 value = hdr->getCommonField1(); // Access Violation
```

I realize the snippet above is missing null pointer checks; I have excluded some of that logic for brevity.  I've traced the code through and everything appears to be running smoothly until an attempt is made to call a method on the base class.  In playing around with the code, I've also seen *member function not present* errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show us teh initialization of `buffer`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not very easy. The buffer is actually passed into the parse function as part of another struct. It's initialization is buried deep in the bowels of some C++ code I dared not touch.  I should note that I simplified the code for my snippet above.

Comment: Either Scott Meyers or Herb Sutter wrote an article (or book section) dealing with "X-ray" types. I don't have my C++ books handy. Does anyone have the reference?

Comment: But what is the static type of `buffer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using the memory in `buffer` without constructing an object there. Since `Header` is polymorphic it contains a virtual table pointer and you can't initialize its data directly (legally you can't even if it's a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) but you would probably get away with it).

You should be using [placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) in order to construct the `Header` object in `buffer`.

```
 parsedHeader = new (&buffer[offset]) HeaderTypeA;
```

Comment: +1 this is likely the reason for the crash.  However, the Virtual Function Table itself takes up space, so he will overwrite the first few fields in the header.  Best not to use virtual inheritance in this application.

Comment: The placement new fixed the access violation, but I also hadn't considered the effect of a vTable in the struct.  Great answer, thanks!

Comment: @Amardeep the virtual function table doesn't reside in each instance, did you mean virtual function pointer? In any case I assume he updates `offset` by `sizeof HeaderTypeX`. There are also alignment issues here which I haven't touched upon in my answer. BTW this is not virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Motti, sorry I meant virtual functions *and* inheritance, not virtual inheritance.